# Is it possible to make a see-through window using HTML/JS/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to make a see-through window when user click in a given position of the screen, something like this:

[image]

It is, I need to highlight an arbitrary area in the screen (with a fixed width and height) in the position where the user clicks.

I have two options:

1. Use a plugin to take screenshots (like [these](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/08/take-webpage-screenshot-html5-jquery-javascript.html)).
2. Create 4 grayed boxes.

I don't like none of these options for different reasons:

1. The use of these plugins exceds my needs and adds an extra page load time and undesired complexity.
2. Manage these boxes may be complex in a future and browser compatibility may be an issue.

So, my question is, is there any way to do this in a simple manner using HTML (HTML5 and canvas is ok), CSS and Javascript/Jquery? A specific Jquery plugin will be an option due I could forget the maintenance of this code.

Comment: have you considered SVG as well?

Comment: No, but it could be an option, yes

Comment: I came up with this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQoVoq?editors=110, but @Saar's solution is more straight-forward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did this once, I am not sure everyone will agree with my implementation but it worked for me at the time:

Create a div in the location you want, set height and width (for window effect);
position the div in the place you wish and then just add outline to it.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/5/);
  background-size: cover;
}
.windowDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: 4000px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="windowDiv"></div>
```

EDIT: use background-color rather than opacity.

2nd EDIT: as A.Wolf suggested you should use outline instead of border for easier positioning.

Comment: Good idea to use the border as a "gray element"

Comment: @Ivan `outline` would be easier edit: oops, i missed `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: See using `outline` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/x50t20uz/  **and** `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Saar if you need to set position specifically, i think there is

Comment: @A.Wolff I guess you're right, although you can just calculate it easily

Comment: @Saar Using your posted code, can you provide working sample because i'm unable to do it? I'm sure you are missing `position: absolute;`, right?

Comment: The potential downside of using outline instead of border is that outline doesn't block clicks. Depending on the use case this might be a good or bad thing. Might be possible to adjust it using `pointer-events` though.

Comment: @Supr Good point, i missed that! Now it is depending expected behaviour like you said

Comment: @Saar so ya, you were missing the positionning in your posted code, thx for fiddle :)

Comment: yea, didn't see you asked about the position absolute